# Azure Application Gateway - Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig vs Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to setup the Azure Application Gateway as shown below

```
$AppGW = Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -ApplicationGateway $AppGW  -Name "webprobe" -Protocol "Http" -HostName $webHostname -Path "/" -Interval 60 -Timeout 300 -UnhealthyThreshold 8 


$AppGW = Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Name "webPoolPortalSetting" -Port 80 -Protocol "Http" -CookieBasedAffinity "Disabled" -Probe $webPortalProbe -RequestTimeout 180
```

I couldn't understand the difference between **Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig & Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings** and microsoft documentation is not helpful.

What exactly Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig & Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/add-azurermapplicationgatewayprobeconfig?view=azurermps-6.13.0) cmdlet adds a [health probe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview) to an Application Gateway. The [Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/add-azurermapplicationgatewaybackendhttpsettings?view=azurermps-6.13.0) cmdlet adds back-end [HTTP settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-http-settings) to an application gateway. They are adding two different things. When you add HTTP settings, you need to associate a health probe that is used to monitor the health of the back end.

But, Both cmdlets rely on an outdated version of Azure PowerShell---`AzureRM` PowerShell.

To get started with the `Az` PowerShell module, see [Install Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.8.0). To learn how to migrate to the `Az` PowerShell module, see [Migrate Azure PowerShell from `AzureRM` to `Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-4.8.0).

Read more information about [Azure PowerShell examples for Azure Application Gateway (AG)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/powershell-samples)

Comment: For easy reference - health probe : Azure Application Gateway by default monitors the health of all resources in its back-end pool and automatically removes any resource considered unhealthy from the pool. - HTTP settings: The application gateway routes traffic to the back-end servers by using the configuration that you specify here.